How to implement type-2 pairing using PBC library?
I am currently working on implementing my cryptographic scheme, which requires the use of Type 2 pairings. However, while using the PBC library, I noticed that there are no explicit Type 2 pairings provided. The library offers symmetric pairings (Types A, B, C, and E) and asymmetric pairings (Types D, F, and G).
My main concern is distinguishing whether the Type D, F, or G parameters are for Type 2 or Type 3 pairings. In particular, I came across a passage in Ben Lynn's PhD thesis:

"When asymmetric pairings are required, for example when DDH must be intractable in at least one of the input groups, one must use D, F, or G pairings. Depending on the needed assumptions, one must also select the second input group carefully as in Section 6.4.2."

However, I found this part somewhat unclear regarding how to determine whether these parameters correspond to Type 2 or Type 3 pairings. So how I can ensure that I'm implementing my scheme with Type 2 pairings using the PBC library?
